# Raspberry Pi disk space problem ( run out of space even no application installed )

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

im new to the raspbian OS. I have a problem where my disk space is running out even when I haven't install any application. Below is the screenshot for my df -h. I have tried expanding the memory size using sudo raspi config but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G   13G  1.5G  90% /
devtmpfs        403M     0  403M   0% /dev
tmpfs           436M     0  436M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           175M  976K  174M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   50M  203M  20% /boot
tmpfs            88M   24K   88M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Memory means RAM usually, but `df` checks DISK space, not RAM. How big is your SD card? Also, please click [edit] and add *textual* output from `df` rather than a picture.

Comment: hi, i use a 16GB SD card.

Comment: Expanding the disk size with `raspi-config` has clearly worked because your `/` partition nearly fills the SD card at 15+GB, so that is not the issue. I can only guess you have created a large file somehow.

Comment: thankyou for the reply, is there a way i can locate large file on the system?

Comment: There are some decent examples here... https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-largest-filesdirectories-on-a-linuxunixbsd-filesystem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command to show large files:

```
find / -size +1000000 -print
```

Or alternatively do an ls on them:

```
find / -size +1000000 -ls
```

This shows all files over 480 megabytes (1000000).